# channel axis dimension not valid python

Tags: python, opencv, scipy

I am having trouble changing the order of dimensions of an image in python. I have changed the dimension of an image from **224x224x3** to **3x224x224**, but m not able to save it as it says **channel axis dimension not valid**. Is there any way I can change the dimensions to **channel** x **width** x **height**?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please include a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), including any Traceback.  See also: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)